# Running Unit Test with Intern 4

Tags: unit-testing, dojo, intern

We migrate our intern 3 test to intern 4.

Unfortunately I get following error for my unit tests (functional tests works)

```
Error: scriptError
No stack or location
Error: Dojo loader error:scriptError
No stack or location
```

My test:

File located:

build/webapp/app/tests/unit/test.js

```
  define([], function () {
    const {registerSuite} = intern.getInterface("object");
    let assert = intern.getPlugin("chai").assert;

    registerSuite("Test", function () {
        return {
            beforeEach() {
                console.log("test");
            },

            tests: {
                defaults() {
                    console.log("test3");
                    console.log("test2");
                },

                toggle() {
                    console.log("test4");
                    console.log("test5");

                    console.log("test8");
                    console.log("test9");
                }
            }
        };
    });
});
```

My intern.json (see below)

```
{
  "loader": {
    "script": "dojo",
    "options": {
      "packages": [
        {
          "name": "app",
          "location": "build/webapp/app"
        },
        {
          "name": "dojo",
          "location": "lib/dojo"
        },
        {
          "name": "dojox",
          "location": "lib/dojox"
        },
        {
          "name": "dijit",
          "location": "lib/dijit"
        },
        {
          "name": "dstore",
          "location": "lib/dstore"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "suites": [
    "./build/webapp/app/tests/unit/test.js"
  ],
  "functionalSuites": [
    "./build/webapp/app/tests/functional/TestDocumentation.js"
  ],
  "functionalTimeouts": {
    "connectTimeout": 60000
  },
  "defaultTimeout": 180000,
  "filterErrorStack": true,
  "tunnel": "selenium",
  "tunnelOptions": {
    "version": "3.8.0",
    "drivers": [
      {
        "name": "ie",
        "arch": "Win64",
        "version": "3.8.0"
      }
    ]
  },
  "debug": true,
  "environments": [
    "node",
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "fixSessionCapabilities": "no-detect"
    }
  ]
```

}

If I execute the unit test in the node envrioment it works fine but after launching to the ie my test failed with the Dojo loader error.

Dojo & intern are aviable in the node_moudles directory.

Best Regards

Kai

Answer (score 0):

Add the lines below to the json file solved my problem

```
{
          "name": "tests",
          "location": "build/webapp/app/tests/"
        }
```